Sendgrid webhook verification return false always - Nodejs, Express
I'm trying to verify the signatures of SendGrid's webhooks in Node.js (Express), but I consistently encounter verification failures. I've tried using various testing methods, including the "Test Integration" feature, test emails, and actual sends, but all of these options result in verification failures.
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { EventWebhook } from "@sendgrid/eventwebhook";

class EmailReport {

    //Saving Email Status
    public async saveEmailStatus(req: Request<any>, res: Response): Promise<any> {
        try {

            const signature = Array.isArray(req.headers['x-twilio-email-event-webhook-signature']) ? req.headers['x-twilio-email-event-webhook-signature'][0] : req.headers['x-twilio-email-event-webhook-signature'];
            const timestamp = Array.isArray(req.headers['x-twilio-email-event-webhook-timestamp']) ? req.headers['x-twilio-email-event-webhook-timestamp'][0] : req.headers['x-twilio-email-event-webhook-timestamp'];

            if (!signature || !timestamp) {
                throw new Error("Sendgrid headers missing");
            }

            const verify = new EventWebhook();
            const payload = JSON.stringify(req.body).split('},{').join('},\r\n{') + '\r\n';
            const publicKey = "MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQghGHFghgfGHFhgfjZ4C3GvemYcGT6dWIHGWHpVmF50mN3avWl7gjkhF54YTfydGHJHGFynNrQ==";

            const ecdsaPublicKey = verify.convertPublicKeyToECDSA(publicKey);

            const isVerified = verify.verifySignature(
                ecdsaPublicKey,
                payload,
                signature,
                timestamp
            );

            console.log({ isVerified });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Webhook error:',  error.message);
        }
    }
}

export default EmailReport;

